# python numpy adding rows to 2d empty array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i want to add rows to an empty 2d numpy array through a loop :

```
yi_list_for_M =np.array([])
M =[]
for x in range(6) :
    #some code 
    yi_m = np.array([y1_m,y2_m])
    yi_list_for_M = np.append(yi_list_for_M,yi_m)
```

the result is :

```
[0.         0.         2.7015625  2.5328125  4.63125    4.29375
 5.7890625  5.2828125  6.05452935 5.47381073 6.175      5.5       ]
```

but i want it  to be :

```
[ [0.         0.]  ,       [2.7015625  2.5328125,] [ 4.63125    4.29375],
 [5.7890625  5.2828125 ], [6.05452935 5.47381073],[ 6.175      5.5 ]      ]
```

and i dont want to use lists i want to use a 1d numpy array inside a 2d numpy array

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you mean, but I think yi_list_for_M = np.append([yi_list_for_M,yi_m]) might be what you want?

Comment: Do not use `np.append` to dynamically build numpy arrays. Use a list instead. `yi_list_for_M = []` and then `yi_list_for_M.append(yi_m)`

Comment: @Psidom could you provide link to reason why not to use append? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Psidom  yes  it works with lists  but i dont want to use lists     i want  to be a numpy array

Comment: `np.array([])` is not a 2d array!  Check its `shape`.

Comment: You can convert the `yi_list_for_M` to numpy array at the end. Use `numpy.append` will be much slower than using list.

Comment: @owo thats what i did  but it's giving me one row  and iwant  it to be multiple rows

Comment: @Psidom okk you , than the conversion would be with numpy.asarray() ??

Comment: `np.append` is a poorly named frontend to `np.concatenate`.  It makes a new array.  List append operates in-place.  You omitted the axis parameter, so you got a 1d array.  Read the docs.

Comment: You can just use the array constructor. `np.array(yi_list_for_M)`

Comment: @hpaulj thank you yes the problem was in the shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you will know what will be the size of each row. If yes then you can do the following:

```py
y = np.empty((0, 3), int) #(0,n), n is the size of your row
for x in range(6):
    y.append(y, np.array([[1, 2]]), axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
yi_list_for_M = np.empty((0,2), int)
for x in range(6):
    y1_m = x**2
    y2_m = x**3
    yi_list_for_M = np.append(yi_list_for_M, np.array([[y1_m, y2_m]]), axis=0)
```